# After add some columns to table, ORM can't find those unless I run reload() in Kohana3

Tags: php, orm, schema, kohana, reload

After I add some columns to the table, my model can't find those new columns but can find the existing ones.

For example, suppose I add a `point` column to the `user` table, and column `name` is existed one.

```
$foo = ORM::factory('user',1);
$foo->name;  // it's ok
$foo->point; // would throw exception:The :property property does not exist in the :class class
$foo->reload();
$foo->point;  // would work
```

As you see, if I add reload() before I fetch the new column, it would work. But I really don't think this is the right way to do that. And I changed the schema before, there was no problem.Looking for a permanent solution..

Comment: 1. Your model has a $_column_cache property with old column list. 
2. May be the first model instance was loaded from session? 

Anyway, you can dump model and analyze $_object property.

Comment: It worked now without any changing.. seems like cache or something. Anyway I don't like to bother this any more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to solve this issue.
Just delete all the files in the directory: `cache/.kohana/`, that is the place where kohana keep the cache of the database schema.